# How can I pass all current environmental variables in a node spawn?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, parent-child, spawn

I am spawning child tasks in Node the following way:

```
function createChildProc(prog, params0, cmdAndEnv) {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    return spawn(prog, params0, cmdAndEnv);
}
```

Where `cmdAndEnv` manually contain the environment variables created during the initial fire up of Node.

Instead of manually issuing all the environmental variables into the spawned child, is there a way to have node automatically inject the current environment variables into the child's environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third argument is used to specify additional options. One of these options is `env` which contains the environment key-value pairs in an object.

```
return spawn(prog, params0, { env: cmdAndEnv });
```

See the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) for more details.

Comment: So `env` deafults to `process.env` hmm. If that were true, how come none of my environmental variables I set in my initial .BAT file flowed in?

Comment: @E.S. What OS? Windows I presume? Unixen (BSD, Linux, Mac) by default pass the parent's environment down to newly created processes/threads. So if you don't do anything you'll get that default behavior. Windows may work differently, I don't know. Haven't had to write a Windows program in the last 10 years.